# length making my page go into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am learning javascript through an online course and whenever I type in `var.length` it kills my page.

I have this code:

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text = "Hello, my name is Paul. What is your name?\
I repeat, my name is Paul. Can't you figure out that my\
name is Paul. Paul!!!!";
var myName = "Paul";
var hits = [];
for (i = 0; text.length; i++) {

}
```

When I run it, my page goes into an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing  the condition statement in for loop, like `i<text.length;`, to break the for loop you need to provide the breaking condition, which is missing. [for](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) more info. And in your case as condition is always true, loop never breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for statement is wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++;) {

}
```

You have to check that `i` is lesser than the length of `text`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I had to declare that in there.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for (i = 0; text.length; i++) {

}
```

Could also be written as:

```
i = 0;

while (text.length)
{
  i++;
}
```

`text.length` will *always* be non-zero in your program, so the loop will keep running forever.

Did you mean:

```
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

}
```

perhaps?